# My shadow implementation isn't working

Tags: c, raytracing

I am trying to implement shadow in my raytracer but it doesn't work.
At the moment this is what I have :

[image]

This my shadow function :

```
int             shadow_sphere(t_lvector *vec, t_obj *obj)
{
  float         a;
  float         b;
  float         c;
  float         delta;
  float         k;
  float         k2;
  t_sphere      *sphere;

  sphere = (t_sphere *)obj->elem;
  a = pow(vec->lx, 2) +
    pow(vec->ly, 2) + pow(vec->lz, 2);
  b = 2 * ((vec->px * vec->lx) +
           (vec->py * vec->ly) +
           (vec->pz * vec->lz));
  c = pow(vec->px, 2) +
    pow(vec->py, 2) + pow(vec->pz, 2) - pow(sphere->radius, 2);
  delta = pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c;
  if (delta >= 0)
    {
      k = (-b + sqrt(delta)) / (2.0f * a);
      k2 = (-b - sqrt(delta)) / (2.0f * a);
      if (k < 0)
        k = k2;
      if (k > 0 && k2 > 0)
        k = (k > k2) ? k2 : k;
      if (k > 0.000001 && k < 1.000001)
        {
          return (1);
        }
    }
  return (0);
}
```

And I call this function like this :

```
 float         cosa;

  if (obj->type_obj == SPHERE)
    cosa = light_up_sphere(rt, obj, vector, light);
  if (obj->type_obj == PLAN)
    cosa = light_up_plan(rt, obj, vector, light);
  if (obj->type_obj == CONE)
    cosa = light_up_cone(rt, obj, vector, light);
  if (obj->type_obj == CYLINDRE)
    cosa = light_up_cylindre(rt, obj, vector, light);
  if (cosa < 0)
    cosa = 0;
  if (apply_shadow(vector, obj) == 1)
    cosa = 0;
  return (cosa);
```

lx, ly and lz are vectors of the light. It starts at the point where my ray hits an objects and ends at the light position.

```
vec->px = (rt->eye->x) + obj->k * rt->vec->x;

vec->py = (rt->eye->y) + obj->k * rt->vec->y;

vec->pz = (rt->eye->z) + obj->k * rt->vec->z;

vec->lx = light->pos.x - vec->px;

vec->ly = light->pos.y - vec->py;

vec->lz = light->pos.z - vec->pz;
```

Do you know where I did something wrong ? 
Thanks.

EDIT: After I did a few changes I got this : 
[image]

I have a shadow but not in the right place.
Do you know why ?

Comment: Maybe you should explain the formulas. I am not very familiar with raytracing but I know a bit about math. If I could understand what the formulas are supposed to achive (geometrically) and/or how you got there, I might be of more help.

Comment: Minor: use `float in `if (k > 0.000001f && k < 1.000001f)`.

Comment: Idea: Switch all to `long double`, temporarily, to see if code is running into some range/precision limitation.

Comment: Check to make sure your vectors are all in the same coordinate system (world vs object space). That turned out to be the issue when I had this problem.